# Java count string index 0 in array

Tags: java, arrays, string, count

Im trying to keep track of occurrences of strings that start with certain letters in an array. Given the following array, count the number of occurrences of strings that start with "T", "B, and "A" for example..

```
String[] month_codes = {"July 2007", "TRUCKS", "APPLES", "BEANS", "COATS", "BANANA", "CODES"}
```

Output would look like this for each month:

```
      T  A  B 
July  2  1  2
Augu ....
Sept ....
```

This is the code I used but it only captures one occurrence

```
public static int extract_counts(String[] month_array){

    for(int i=0; i < month_array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(month_array[i]);
        if(month_array[i].startsWith("T")){
            july_ab++;
            }

        }
        return july_ab;
    }
```

Comment: Is each month a separate array?

Comment: Yes. but initially I had it as one single array where the months and their contents were classified as one element each: {July Truck Apple, August Truck Apple....}

Comment: You are only counting occurrences of strings starting with `T`. You need to count the other two (`A` and `B`) as well. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have and got 0 for both

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is iterate through all of the items once, counting the number of occurrences. Then I'd print the results.

The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, would be to use an array of integers representing the 26 letters in the English alphabet:

```
int[] frequency = new int[26];
// frequency[0] is the number of words that start with A
```

Here, we can take advantage of the fact that Java initializes an integer arrays with all zeroes.

Then we'd iterate through the `month_array` and count how many words start with each letter.

```
for( String word : month_array ) {
  char firstLetter = word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
  int index = firstLetter - 'a'; // a = 0, b = 1, etc.
  frequency[index]++;
}
```

At the end of this for-loop, the `frequency` array now contains how many words start with each letter. We could print them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    System.out.print( frequency[i] ); 
}
```

Of course, this would be in order from A to Z. You'd also probably want to print the headers with the letters A-Z first before iterating through your months.

In your example, your first word is "July 2007" -- of course you'd need to omit this first item before counting since you'd otherwise be artificially incrementing (for example) the 'J' counter.

```
public int[] extractCounts( String[] month_array ) {
   int[] frequency = new int[26];

    for(int i = 1; i < month_array.length; i++) { 
        // here, we start at 1 to omit the 'July 2007' record
        String word = month_array[i];
        char firstLetter = word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        int index = firstLetter - 'a';
        frequency[index]++;
    }
    return frequency;
}

public void printCounts(String month, int[] frequencies) {
    System.out.print(month + "\t");
    for(int frequency : frequencies) {
        System.out.print(frequency);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer, I like the way you used the index however my code is giving me 0 for all, I will keep trying though thanks for the input

Comment: This is possibly why my input is wrong.. correct me if needed:

    String july_all = allStrings.get(0);

String[] to_arr = new String[] {july_all};

My thought here is to create a string for each month in allStrings (allStrings is an ArrayList) and convert each string month into an array then go through the counts

Comment: What is `july_all`? If it's a comma-separated string, you'd need to convert it into an array using something like String's `split` method. In your question you said you had an array of strings, but it sounds like you just have one string that you haven't converted to an array yet. `new String[] { july_all }` will give you a single-element array, where the item at index 0 is the contents of the string `july_all`....

Comment: yes, it appears what I have is a single element in an array and index 0 always points at "J"

Comment: Yes. That's what you did when you called `new String[] { july_all }` -- you made a single-element array. If you wanted to split at a comma or something you'd have to do something like `String[] values = july_all.split(",")`.

Comment: Thanks figured it out. Had to split by "\n" since each string is separated by a newline. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways.

I am providing you a way which can find the occurrences (Starting chars) using single loop and Map to store only occurrence of String start with "A", "B" and "T".

Here is the code:

```
  public static Map<String, Integer> extract_counts(String[] month_array){
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i < month_array.length; i++){
        //System.out.println(month_array[i]);
        if(month_array[i].startsWith("T")){
            if(map.containsKey("T")){
                map.put("T", map.get("T") + 1);
            }else {
                map.put("T", 1);
            }
        }
        if(month_array[i].startsWith("A")){
            if(map.containsKey("A")){
                map.put("A", map.get("A") + 1);
            }else {
                map.put("A", 1);
            }
        }
        if(month_array[i].startsWith("B")){
            if(map.containsKey("B")){
                map.put("B", map.get("B") + 1);
            }else {
                map.put("B", 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
```

Calling the method:

```
String[] month_codes = {"July 2007", "TRUCKS", "APPLES", "BEANS", "COATS", "BANANA", "CODES"};
System.out.println(extract_counts(month_codes));
```

Will get output like this:

`{A=1, B=2, T=1}`

Comment: How would I then call this function from another?

Comment: Gave that in the answer!

Comment: my bad.. its getting late

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] month_codes = ...;
Map<Character, Long> result = Arrays.stream(month_codes)
                                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                             str -> Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(0)),
                                             Collectors.counting()));
```

So, `Map<Character, Long>` contains following data:

```
'a' -> 1
'b' -> 2
'c' -> 2
't' -> 1
'j' -> 1
```

Comment: Using your approach and everyones only counts the first letter in my Array, that being July.